# Can intermixing std::'s and boost::'s ::bind and ::function cause problems?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, std

I think the answer to this is no, but I just want to be sure.

If I have a `std::function` as a parameter in a function, is there any problem with passing in a `boost::bind` and vice-versa?

edit:

I discovered that the placeholders used by boost::bind are imported directly into the namespace when you include boost\bind.h, and they are incompatible with std::bind.  For std::bind you have to refer to the placeholders explicit, like so: std::placeholders::_1, or do some other typedef or using magic to make them both available simultaneously.

Comment: You might want to be aware of what a nested bind expression is and check how different libraries interact together in that respect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The whole purpose of `std::` (and `boost::`) `function` is that they can accept *any* function object which can be called with the correct signature- including lambdas, functors, and the result of any kind of binding. They do not care where your function object came from or what type it is.

You can even bind them to each other, although I'm not really sure why you'd want to.

Comment: Thanks for verify that for me.  I did discover that boost imports its placeholders into the namespace which conflicts with std::bind's placeholders, so you have to explicitly name std's placeholders using std::placeholders::_1